# Movement weird problem with asteroids replica in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is part of my code.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        _turnDirection = 1.0f;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        _turnDirection = -1.0f;
    }
```

I have a weird problem: The player will turn left but wont turn right. IDk why.
if you want the full code i can provide that: https://pastebin.com/CJ0wAVi0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with your `FixedUpdate`. Instead of only rotating when `_turnDirection` is greater than zero, try rotating whenever it is not equal to zero since `_turnDirection` can be negative.

Comment: Oh thanks but i dont know how to do that. You see, i used to do use the disequal sign but it wont work

Comment: Edit: used !=, and the issue was fixed, thaks to @TheMikeste!